# Open web.whatsapp in webview android

Tags: java, android, webview, whatsapp

I am trying to open "https://web.whatsapp.com/" in my android app(in webview) since 2 days but just failed to do that.For a first time it is showing me QR code page successfully, But second time it is redirect to another url and not showing actual one.

I am using User Agent Like this :

String newUA="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1";

I already tried to   setDesktopMode(webView, true);

Thanks in advance.